# Is there a way to capture the inputs into a command line program being executed by another program on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I am doing some video editing and I have found a program called Any Video Converter (AVC) which is free and easy to use.  I have found some presets that are working perfectly for me in terms of the output.

I know for a fact that Any Video Converter is just a nice wrapper around the FFMPEG command line tool (which is true of most every other video converter out there I am sure.)

While this works for me, I would much rather use ffmpeg directly so that I could write my own automation scripts to speed things up.

However, I do not want to spend hours and days learning ffmpeg.  (Maybe one day.)  So my desire would be to somehow "capture/log" the settings that are being used by AVC when I do the conversion.

Is there a way to do this in windows?  Some kind of cmd "listener or trace tool" that you could turn on, run from  AVC which would be logged by the listener and then turn off the listener.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about AVC, but it is easily possible to capture command line arguments on existing processes using Process Explorer.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Start the encoding, open process explorer, pick up the ffmpeg process, right click, select " properties" and there you go. If you just need to get the command line of one process, this is one of the simplest ways.

[image: properties]

Or, if you really need a monitoring tool, Process Monitor will do that job for you.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx

1. Run Process Monitor, set a new filter on "Process Monitor Filter" dialogue of "**Process Name** is ffmpeg.exe" and click "add" like below. You may add AVC's module name (avc.exe?) additionally there if necessary. (I entered CMD.EXE as I didn't have AVC & FFMPEG) 
   [image: Filter]
2. Click OK to close the dialogue and deselect Registry, File, Network monitoring as we don't care them now. The last item (processes & threads) should be selected. 
   [image: Monitoring]
3. Run AVC. Whenever it calls FFMPEG.EXE, the internal activities will be recorded on this window like below. Check "Process Start" operations - as I don't have the tools you want to monitor, I tested this with cmd.exe and you see the parameter "mycommandline" I entered for testing. 
   [image: Result]

Good luck!